# Open source engine / software for makruk?

Tags: makruk

There are open-source engines for chess, shogi (e.g. [gShogi](http://johncheetham.com/projects/gshogi/)), xiangqi (e.g. [XiangQi Engine](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xiangqi-engine/)) and other strategy board games.

Are there any open-source engines for [makruk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makruk)? (I.e. not just freeware.)

Note: this is not a request for recommendations, but an attempt to find out whether any such open-source engines exist at all. I could not find any at the time when I posted this question.

Answer (score 5):

The only open-source makruk engines I know of are:

- [fairymax](http://home.hccnet.nl/h.g.muller/CVfairy.html)
- [Sjaak II](http://www.eglebbk.dds.nl/program/chess-index.html)
- [Stockfish](https://github.com/ianfab/Makruk-Stockfish)

The latter is my attempt of adapting Stockfish for makruk. Below you can find some recent [test results](https://github.com/ddugovic/Stockfish/issues/426#issuecomment-354451194). I can not give an estimate of how these engines compare to strong human players though.

```
Rank Name                          Elo     +/-   Games   Score   Draws 
1    stockfish-mak-f364111         359     103      80   88.8%   15.0%    
2    Bilis_v1.0                    127      65      80   67.5%   32.5%    
3    sjaakii-1.4.1                 -61      60      80   41.2%   40.0%    
4    fairymax-5.0b                -174      62      80   26.9%   38.8%    
5    NebiyuAlien                  -185      55      80   25.6%   46.2%
```